# Resolving Transaction Failures and Debugging Issues with Chainlink API Calls in a Blockchain Project

Tags: nestjs, stripe-payments, blockchain, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm facing challenges with Chainlink in my project, specifically with transaction failures and log erasure when calling APIs from a Chainlink consumer contract.

**Issue:** Transactions revert when using Chainlink to call APIs, erasing all logs and impeding debugging.

**Specific Problem:** Success with GET API calls, but POST method (payment API) returns a bad request.

**Error Message:** "InternalServerErrorException: execution reverted (unknown custom error) (action="estimateGas")".

**Documentation Gap:** Inadequate guidance on making POST requests via Chainlink Functions.

Seeking advice on resolving these issues, especially for executing POST API calls and retaining logs for debugging.

This below code snippet is where I initiate transaction

```
**../requestSource.js**
const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/payment/transfer',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    jobProposalId: args[0],
    amount: args[1],
    milestoneOrder: args[2],
  },
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(apiResponse));
if (apiResponse.error) {
  throw Error(apiResponse.error);
}
const { data } = apiResponse;
return Functions.encodeString(data);
```

```
 const source = readFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, '../requestSource.js'),
      ).toString();
  
 const args = ['65ad521cfa8f23xxxxxxx', '375', '1'];

 const response = await simulateScript({
        source: source,
        args: args,
        bytesArgs: [], // bytesArgs - arguments can be encoded off-chain to bytes.
        secrets: {}, // no secrets in this example
      });
```

Simulating this with POST request throws a BadRequest.

Even if the simulation response is successful or not the contract method invocation fails with the error - `"InternalServerErrorException: execution reverted (unknown custom error) (action="estimateGas")"`

```
   const tx = await contract.markMilestoneCompleted(
        updateContractDto.contractAddress,
        updateContractDto.milestoneId,
        subscriptionId,
        donId,
        source,
        args,
        gasLimit,
      );
      await tx.wait();
```

Expected behaviour is marking the milestone completed updating the contract and initiation of the payment that should not return any errors.

Comment: In chainlink functions, to promise the process to fetch data from web2 api safe and decentralized, there are multiple nodes to transfer the call the same API and aggregate the results. In your case, I guess you just want to call the API once to make the payment, while the API(http://localhost:4000/payment/transfer) is actually called 4-5 times. Is this the behaviors you expected in your case?

Comment: Yes, we expect the payment API to be called only once. Is there any way to ensure that only one node processes our request?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That is currently impossible to do that. The usage of Oracle is to relay data and any computing service from web2 to on-chain smart contracts. What you want to do is to use Oracle to move data from on-chain to off-chain and that is not the job of Oracle. I think you should create a service to track the status of smart contracts and call the off-chain API, since this process does not require to be decentralized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, our use case is to trigger a payment from on-chain contract method. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this within our contract method

Comment: I think you can build a back-end service to track the events of a specific smart contract and trigger the payment when the flag is on.

Comment: Mentioned in my answer below, but another option is to use Chainlink Direct Requests, which will allow you to make your POST request only once, and eliminate the need to host your own infrastructure that monitors blockchain state. The downside here is that you're trusting a single oracle provider to make your request (potential centralization risk and/or SPOF), so it's important to understand this tradeoff and choose a reputable oracle with a redundant infrastructure and a clear SLA.

Answer (score 1):

By the error message, the problem is from interacting with the deployed contract. It seems related to the [CALL_EXCEPTION in estimateGas](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/4240), but hard to confirm as Chainlink doesn't return the complete error message.

If it was a CALL_EXCEPTION in estimateGas, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151766/call-exception-in-estimategas-with-local-ganache) for resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink community oracle here.

As Frank mentioned, when using Chainlink Functions, your target API will be called multiple times per request, so it's important to consider this when building out your app.

One way around this is to use Chainlink's Any API (ie, Direct Request) pattern, whereby your request will only go through a single Chainlink oracle, therefore ensuring that your API call only occurs once. While there are obvious downsides to using a single Chainlink oracle (ie, you need to trust the oracle company not to manipulate your data), there are many reputable oracles who run their oracles on highly-redundant infrastructure spread over multiple datacenters and regions. This will eliminate the need to run any additional infrastructure yourself in monitoring the blockchain state / posting your request.

If you're interested in finding a Chainlink oracle to serve this type of request, you can A) join the Chainlink Official Discord server and post your requirement to **#operator-requests**, or B) use the website of a known/reputable Chainlink oracle for a self-service approach (we at LinkWell Nodes provide documentation and code samples for initiating a singular HTTP POST request from your smart contract, including the related oracle address and Job ID).

I hope that helps, and let me know if you have any questions!